# How to stop repeating to set the same attribute to actions in Navigation Graph?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have already set six fragments in my Navigation Graph. Each fragment looks like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.MainFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >

    <action android:id="@+id/action_main_fragment_to_movies_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/movies_fragment"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>
</fragment>
```

For each one of my fragments, I set `popEnterAnim`, `popExitAnim`, `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` attribute for the action. Is there any way I can stop repeating the set of the same attributes? Something like a "style". You write once and then just apply it. Thanks.